# Passing 'this' as parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<label id="copyAddress" class="copyAddress" onclick="CopyAddress(this);">
    Copy Address
</label>
```

**JS:**

```
function CopyAddress(copyAddressLink) {    
  PopulateTarget(copyAddressLink);   
}

function PopulateTarget(link) {
  var targetGroup = $(link).closest('someClass');    
}
```

In PopulateTarget function 'link' variable is undefined, while in CopyAddress it has values as is should.

What can cause this problem? Is there some restriction for passing parameters in Java Script? How this should behave? If you need more code to post please tell me.

Comment: [Seems to be working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/yyNW2/).

Comment: Are you sure that `link` is `undefined` in your `PopulateTarget` function?  Or is the return value of `$(link)` `undefined`?  Above `PopulateTarget` in `CopyAddress` put `console.log("CopyAddressLink value: ", copyAddressLink);`  and in `PopulateTarget` put `console.log("Link Value: ", link);` above `var targetGroup = ...`  Then look at your console to see what the values are.  If you post your HTML structure, we can see if your selector in `.closest()` is actually working.  I am betting that is the cause.

Comment: Furthermore: are you sure you have jQuery on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are anyhow using jQuery, why are you using obtrusive Javascript?

Use this instead:

**HTML:**

```
<label id="copyAddress" class="copyAddress">Copy Address</label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#copyAddress').click(function(){
        var targetGroup = $(this).closest('.someClass');    
    });
});
```

Comment: Should be '.someClass` he has a mistake there... there is no element type `someClass`

Comment: @gdoron - Correct. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a dot on "someClass", it should be ".someClass".

Maybe your code will work after you fix that. However: since you're using jQuery (it seems you are), you should attach the click handler the jQuery way, instead of inline on the HTML. This means:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#copyAddress').click(CopyAddress);
})

function CopyAddress() {    
    PopulateTarget(this);   
}

function PopulateTarget(link) {
    var targetGroup = $(link).closest('someClass');    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not intermix your HTML and JS. You should instead attach your JS handlers programmatically in your JS code:

```html
<!-- note: no onclick in this html -->
<label id="copyAddress" class="copyAddress">Copy Address</label>
```

```js
// Wait until the page is loaded before starting to look for elements
$(function(){

  // Assuming jQuery 1.7
  $('#copyAddress').on('click',copyAddress);

  // …alternatively, for older jQuery
  $('#copyAddress').click(copyAddress);

  function copyAddress(evt){
    // The 'target' property of the event object passed in is the object
    // upon which the event was first triggered.
    PopulateTarget(evt.target);
  }
});
```

In the case of the above, you could just use `this` instead of `evt.target`, since you bound the event directly on that object. However, this becomes more powerful if you have a variety of items on the page that perform this function. You can attach the event handler once to some parent object, and then ask—during the callback—which element was clicked on. That would look like:

```
// Watch for any element with a copyAddress class to be clicked on,
// even if they are added after this code has run
$(document.body).on('click','.copyAddress',function(evt){
  var target = evt.target;
  console.log("You clicked on",target);
});
```

Comment: `end`?! You mixed something up ;)

Comment: Eek! Thanks for noticing :) Too much Ruby and JS at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are using jQuery:

You can use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to bind `this` to a specific value. It is used like this:

```
jQuery.proxy(function () { console.log(this); }, this);
```

Comment: However, this is not necessary in this situation.